# Example of closed and bounded but not compact in R

Tags: analysis

Define metric on $\mathbb R$ by $d_1(x,y)=\min(|x-y|,1)$. Give a example of a subsets that are closed and bounded, but not compact in the metric space with respect to this metric.\
I was thinking on using neighborhoods of radius 2 but I don't know if it works. Any suggestion or a example may be helpful.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (someone please point out if I am mistaken), this metric generates the same topology on $\mathbb R$ as the usual metric and since compactness is a topological property, this means that compact sets with respect to this metric are the same as those with respect to the usual metric; i.e., a set is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

Comment: I prove that if the sets are open with respect to the usual metric iff they also be open with respect to d_1. Also  a set $A\subset \mathbb R$ is compact with respect to $d_1$ if and only if it is compact with respect to $d$.

Comment: @User8128 Indeed, it induces the same topology, but topology does not induce a notion of boundedness. Boundedness is a metric property and the given metric is not equivalent to the usual one. Btw., what is the ball of radius 2 in this metric? (Hint: there is only one…)

Comment: Ah, good note @Dirk! I'm still a novice at topology

Answer (score 1):

The original question was:

> **Q1:** Find a closed  bounded set that isn't compact.

But note that every set is bounded with respect to the given metric, because all distances are less than or equal to one. So, since boundedness holds vacuously, the problem is equivalent to:

> **Q2:** Find a closed set that isn't compact.

Generally speaking, for a metric space $X$, the following are equivalent:

1. $X$ is noncompact.
2. $X$ has a closed noncompact subspace.

Indeed, since the whole of $X$ is closed, (i) implies (ii). On the other hand, if $X$ is compact, then all closed subspaces of $X$ are compact, so not (i) implies not (ii).

So, if there are any noncompact closed sets to be found, the whole space will need to be one of them. So at the end of the day the question amounts to just:

> **Q3:** Show that the whole space isn't compact.

This is true. In fact $\mathbb{R}$ with the given metric has the same topology as $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric. So, if you know that the standard real line is noncompact, then you see right away that the line with your metric is noncompact too. You could also give an explicit open cover with no finite subcover, such as the union of all balls of radius $1/2$.